# how to Create Url in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

custom route is not working in my case

i am trying to Create a URL in mvc4.

Route url:-

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DocumentDetails",
                url: "DocumentDetails",
            defaults: new { Controller = "Home", action = "DocumentDetails", DocumentId = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
```

Controller:-

```
 public void DocumentDetails(int DocumentId)
        {
           some code
        }
```

i am expecting following url.
just i am try to remove my controller Name in url.

www.mysite.com/DocumentDetails?DocumentId=15

Current working url

www.mysite.com/Home/DocumentDetails?DocumentId=15

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapMvcAttributeRoutes.
add this to your controller

```
[Route("DocumentDetails/{DocumentId}")]
public ActionResult DocumentDetails(int DocumentId)
    {
       some code
    }
```

now documentid set as url.
you need to add this in your RouteConfig

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```